# Pegar parte de uma string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

Como faço para pegar só até a `,` da string a seguir:

```
Ninguem ninguem, todos
```

Resultado esperado:

```
Ninguem ninguem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz assim com regex:

```
string campo = campo_texto.Text;

string[] nome = Regex.Split(campo, ",");
```

Answer (score 4):

Deixo aqui mais uma alternativa, e com os tempos de execução de 10.000.000 vezes.

```
string texto = "Ninguem ninguem, todos";  

string resultado = texto.Substring(0, texto.IndexOf(',')); // 0.383s

string resultado = texto.Split(',')[0]; // 1.400s

string resultado = new string(texto.TakeWhile(c => c != ',').ToArray()); //5.204s

string resultado = string.Concat(texto.TakeWhile(c => c != ',')); // 6.746s

string resultado = Regex.Split(texto, ",")[0]; // 8.595s
```

Comment: Isso são segundos? como você gerou esses valores de tempos? fiz um teste aqui e a variação de tempo mal chega a milissegundos, que dirá segundos.

Comment: Fiz 1 Fiddle do comparativo, seria uma boa ajustar essa resposta sua: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AzJFre

Comment: @Barbetta 10.000.000 de vezes.... coloque um ciclo em cada uma....

Comment: Aaah sim, com a explicação ficou claro.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar algo parecido com isso,

```
string data = "Ninguem ninguem, todos";
string[] words = data.Split(",");
```

Isso poderia ser resolvido com regex.

Answer (score 0):

Também tem a opção de usar o `LastIndexOf` com o `Substring`. Onde você indica *startIndex* e o tamanho que quer pegar da *string*

```
string texto = "Ninguem ninguem, todos";        
string textoCortado = texto.Substring(0, texto.LastIndexOf(","));
Console.WriteLine(textoCortado);
```